# Is git pull really same as git fetch+merge?

Tags: git, fetch, branch, pull

I saw so many questions here and on the web which say that git pull is the same thing is doing git fetch and then merging. I was pulling something at work this other day using git pull and it kept saying to me that my local branch is already up to date although there were changes made by other developers. However, when I did a git fetch and then did a git pull, I was able to pull the changes. If git pull already does a git fetch, why did just doing a git pull not work?
I would appreciate the response.

Comment: This doesn't seem reproducible to me.  A `git pull` should have updated whatever branch you were on.  Can you show us exactly what you were doing?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "yes", but the long answer is only *mostly* "yes".

If your Git version is older than 2.6, your `git pull` is a simple—well, OK, maybe not so simple, weighing in at over 300 lines—[shell script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b7b314711ad28b129e6c5916eee1f2036ffa94df/git-pull.sh) that [runs this line](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b7b314711ad28b129e6c5916eee1f2036ffa94df/git-pull.sh#L251):

```
git fetch $verbosity $progress $dry_run $recurse_submodules --update-head-ok "$@" || exit 1
```

The `$@` here encompasses most of the arguments people usually type into `git pull`:

```
git pull origin master
```

for instance would run:

```
git fetch origin master
```

(A few options are removed from `$@` to be passed to the rebase or merge command if appropriate.)

Since Git version 2.6.0, `git pull` is now coded in C, but it still invokes the same `git fetch` operation—it's just faster on Windows as it no longer has to get a shell involved.

The part where the answer is only *mostly* "yes" is that *after* fetching, the remaining part of `git pull` is not necessarily `git merge`.  It can be `git rebase`, or even in a few corner cases, `git read-tree`.  For details, see the rest of the script.

Note that if you have more than one remote, and you run `git fetch` with no additional arguments, Git will use the current branch's configured remote if there is one, or `origin` if there is no configured remote.  When you run `git pull remote branch-name`, you are supplying a named remote, which will override the current branch's configured remote (if any).  So that can be a source of differences: if the current branch has no upstream set, `git fetch` will fetch from `origin`, but `git pull otherremote foo` will fetch from remote `otherremote`.